# Stuart platform

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has there been any work to support 6DOF stuart gough platforms or similar parallel geometries?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/112016/stuart-platform/) by [hojalot](https://answers.ros.org/users/10091/hojalot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
See here:
http://answers.ros.org/question/9050/using-ros-for-a-delta-robot/

---

Originally posted by [David Galdeano](https://answers.ros.org/users/9481/david-galdeano/) with karma: 357 on 2013-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hojalot](https://answers.ros.org/users/10091/hojalot/) on 2013-12-19**:
This discussion was a few years ago, and I got the sense that at that time support for parallel mechanisms required workarounds.  Have any of the proposed workaround been incorporated in to the base ros or are there any specific examples?

**Comment by [David Galdeano](https://answers.ros.org/users/9481/david-galdeano/) on 2013-12-19**:
Kinematics loop crated in parallel robots contain physical constraints which must be solve at high rate, maybe ROS is not adapted for these constraints and cant separate the command algorithms and the motor control.

You can write a small controller (IK) for the robot an take advantage of the ROS framework by using its own communication mechanisms.